# How to print the elements of two lists together

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have two lists with a different number of elements. I would like to print each element of the first list with each element of the second list and so on.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ["banana", "orange", "pear"]
```

The output I would like to obtain:

```
1 banana

1 orange

1 pear

2 banana 

2 orange
```

and so on.

I tried this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ["banana", "orange", "pear"]

for i,k in zip(a,b):
    print(i, k)
```

but I get this output:

```
1 banana
2 orange
3 pear

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = ["banana", "orange", "pear"]
>>> for x in it.product(a, b):
...     print(x)
... 
(1, 'banana')
(1, 'orange')
(1, 'pear')
(2, 'banana')
(2, 'orange')
(2, 'pear')
(3, 'banana')
(3, 'orange')
(3, 'pear')
(4, 'banana')
(4, 'orange')
(4, 'pear')
(5, 'banana')
(5, 'orange')
(5, 'pear')
```

Comment: How can I just print a string instead of a tuple?

Comment: @Carl You can also use `print(*x)` if you don't like to print the tuple.